# D3 - How to make visualization with a partition layout have equally divided sectors?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to achieve a visualization with a partition layout. What I need is the divided sections have equally the same width, like this:

[image: Desired outcome]

But what I currently have is this:

[image: Current version]

You can find the current version working [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bfpmg) on Codepen, but I copy the code here also:

```
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
    color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["rgb(255,247,236)","rgb(254,232,200)","rgb(253,212,158)","rgb(253,187,132)","rgb(252,141,89)","rgb(239,101,72)","rgb(215,48,31)","rgb(179,0,0)","rgb(127,0,0)"]);

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .children(function(d) { return isNaN(d.value) ? d3.entries(d.value) : null; })
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var data = {
  'root': {

    'asdf': {
      'a': {
        'kdjfklsfj': 1,
        'kdjfklsfsj': 1
      },
      'b': 1
    },

    'bnm': {
      'c': 1,
      'd': {
        'lsdkjfdkljsf': {
          'lsdkfj': 1,
          'kldsjfdlk': 1
        },
        'kdjfkjsdfk': 1
      }
    }

  }
};

var rect = vis.selectAll("rect")
    .data(partition(d3.entries(data)[0]))
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.dx); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.dy); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.key); })
    .on("click", click);

function click(d) {
  x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
  y.domain([d.y, 1]).range([d.y ? 20 : 0, h]);

  rect.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y); });
}
```

What I found is that altering the data values (currently all items are valued "1"), increase the width of the elements naturally, but how can I make it have a equally divided boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the partition function to calculate the width of each block as either the value (if it has one), or the sum of its children's values.  It sounds like you want to use the *number* of children as the weight in the latter case, so that e.g. the top node is split into 1/2 and 1/2 instead of 4/7 and 3/7.

**Edit:** The d3's partition() object is designed to determine the size of a parent elements based on the sum of the sizes of its children, whereas (if I understand your use case) you want the sizes of the children to be apportioned from the size of their parents, based on the number of its siblings.

To get this to work you'll have to manage the leaf node object values to 'trick' d3 into doing what you want.  Here's a `data` object that gets the first level to have even lengths:

```
var data = {
  'root': {

    'asdf': {
      'a': {
        'kdjfklsfj': 1/6,
        'kdjfklsfsj': 1/6
      },
      'b': 1/6
     },

    'bnm': {
      'c': 1/8,
      'd': {
        'lsdkjfdkljsf': {
          'lsdkfj': 1/8,
          'kldsjfdlk': 1/8
        },
        'kdjfkjsdfk': 1/8
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In other words, you have to manage the data to fit d3's expectations.  It's not d3 manipulation that should do this, it's your data generator.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to say that I'm newbie with D3 and mainly this code is from a example I found. Can you point specifically how I should edit the code to change that according with what you suggest?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's more clear now. One more question, what's the criteria to select those ratios (1/6, 1/8)?

Comment: Those are the "share" of the total, based on the number of siblings in the chain to the root.  E.g. under /root/asdf there are three total children, and /root has two children, so each child under /root/asdf gets 1/3 * 1/2 = 1/6.  I didn't take the grandchildren into account in the above; so really each child of `a` should get 1/8, and `b` should get `1/4`, and similarly for the other side of the tree.  The key is that the sum of the children of each node should equal the node's share.  Hope that makes sense.